# react-router-dom state returns error on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am new to react-router-dom, I was calling `Data` inside
of the **ParentPage.jsx** and mapped it using **Card.jsx** and it returned cards of data. In the
**Card.jsx** I passed the data to the **ChildPage** page using `<Link/>` and it worked, but if I'm going to refresh the child page it returns an error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined`. I have also tried storing the data on the `localStorage` but it is still returning the same error. I hope someone can help me.

Here are my code snippets.

### ParentPage.jsx

```
  const [establishment, setEstablishment] = useState([]);
  const Data = () => {
    ...
  };

  const cards = useMemo(() => {
    return establishment.map((establishment) => (
        <Card establishment={establishment} />
    ));
  });

  ...
      {cards}
  ...
```

### Card.jsx

```
  const [details] = useState(establishment);
  return (
    <>
      <text>{details.name}</text>
      <Link
        to={{
          pathname: "/establishments/details",
          state: { details },
        }}
      >
        <Button>
          Details
        </Button>
      </Link>
    </>
  );
```

### ChildPage.jsx

```
  const {state} = useLocation();
  const [data, setData] = useState(state?.details);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem(data.id, JSON.stringify(data));
  }, [data]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updatedData = window.localStorage.getItem(data.id);
    if (updatedData !== null) setData(JSON.parse(updatedData));
  }, []);

   ...
     ...data.color
   ...
```

Here is the `Error`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are on the right track, but the logic is a little mixed up. Route state is very transient, it only exists during the route transition and while the receiving component remains mounted. Reloading the page reloads the entire React app. Any state in memory is lost.

Current code:

```
const location = useLocation();
const [data, setData] = useState(location.state?.details); // (A)

useEffect(() => {
  window.localStorage.setItem(data.id, JSON.stringify(data)); // (B)
}, [data]);

useEffect(() => {
  const updatedData = window.localStorage.getItem(data.id);
  if (updatedData !== null) setData(JSON.parse(updatedData));
}, []);

...

  .... data.color // (C)
...
```

Here's what I see occurring:

1. Navigate to child page with defined state, the `data` state is initialized to `location.state.details` (A), and the component renders with defined `data.color` (C). No error.
2. The first `useEffect` hook runs and persists the `data` state to local storage under the defined key `data.id` (B).
3. The second `useEffect` hook runs and reads from localStorage using defined `data.id` key and since it's not null enqueues a `data` state update.
4. Reload the page.
5. The app remounts. This `ChildPage` component remounts. The `data` state is initialized to the undefined `location.state` value (A). Error thrown accessing `data.color` on the initial render (C).

## Solution

The `data` state should be initialized from `location.state.data` if it exists, then fallback to localStorage if it exists, then possibly fallback to a base value. Use only a single `useEffect` hook to persist the local state to localStorage when it updates. Use a storage key that is always defined.

```
const { state } = useLocation();
const [data, setData] = useState(() => {
  return state?.details || JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("details")) || {};
});

useEffect(() => {
  window.localStorage.setItem("details", JSON.stringify(data));
}, [data]);

...

  .... data.color
...
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Mr. Drew, your solution works, but I have a little problem because I'm passing dynamic data it only stores the data from the first item that I am pressing in the item list, and then the rest does not. I hope you can still help me.

Comment: @jeffigy I can certainly still help. Can you clarify what exactly you mean by "passing dynamic data" and "it only stores the data from the first item that I am pressing in the item list, and then the rest does not"? You can edit your post with an actual [mcve] that includes both the parent and child components and what & how you are passing data, and clarify what exactly the issue is you are observing.

Comment: Hello Mr. @Drew, I edited my post. If I will press a card in the ParentPage and then redirects to the ChildPage it stores the data in the localStorage, but if I will go back to the ParentPage and press another card with different data, the data from the previous card that I have pressed will display and not the current data.

Comment: @jeffigy I see, so you want the route state to be more the "source of truth". You could likely swap these values in the state initializer function. That said, this data is starting to seem more like a global app state value. The app could probably benefit from storing the data in a React context and use a dynamic route path with an `id` parameter that the child component can use to access the data, and configure the app to persist the Context value to/from localStorage when the app mounts.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the parsing of data not the link it self. It would have helped a lot if you had showed some code and the full error message

Comment: Pardon me, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of usage, the best practice would be using query param in react-router-dom, so that you can pass your value and by refreshing the page will work the same, you can check if there is no query param in the child component you can redirect the user back

I think this blog will help to handle it https://denislistiadi.medium.com/react-router-v6-fundamental-url-parameter-query-strings-customizing-link-57b75f7d63dd